# logic for matching two images in a game

Tags: java, android, image, match

Hi i want to compare logic matches in a image-grid that is populated on random.
right now i have two arrays were the the images on the matching positions in the arrays is a "logic match".

i then loop them all into an arraylist that i shuffle and then populate my grid that implements checkable.

but i want to be able to assign some kind of constant value to the drawabls in the original arrays when looping them into the arraylist
so that in the end i can chose two images i think match and compare their value.

but i don't relay know how to go about this.
many tanks.

Comment: Sounds interesting but can you elaborate this a little bit specific. Maybe some image for clarity, what do you mean by logic match?

Comment: the final graphic are not in place in the test code so right now its just a bunch of pikachu images with a 1 written  on the match :P. but the the final ide is a kind of math+logic game for kids where 12 cards holding 9 slots for marbles are displayed on the grid and the object is to match 2 cards so that their marble pattern together make a complete one. and try to get as many matches as possible in a set time-frame. but im a noob at this so its moving at a snails pace haha.

Comment: Well then your question title is a total miss, you are not matching actual images, you are trying to make a logic for matching game which is completely different :)

Comment: ok,sorry haha. hopefully its i bit clearer now, my brain is in code mode where i think everybody can read my mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

I created a game that may help you? Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/jmccommas/AhPfV/

```
jquery code
var lastSelected;
var score = 0;
var boxopened = "";
var imgopened = "";
var num = 0;
var moves = 0;
$(function () {
    $("div.row div img").addClass('hidden');
    addImg();
    click();
    check();
    shuffle();


});

function randomFromTo(from, to) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}

function shuffle() {
    var children = $("#boxcard").children();
    var child = $("#boxcard div:first-child");

    var array_img = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        array_img[i] = $("#" + child.attr("id") + " img").attr("src");
        child = child.next();
    }

    var child = $("#boxcard div:first-child");

    for (z = 0; z < children.length; z++) {
        randIndex = randomFromTo(0, array_img.length - 1);

        // set new image
        $("#" + child.attr("id") + " img").attr("src", array_img[randIndex]);
        array_img.splice(randIndex, 1);

        child = child.next();
    }
}


function check(el) {

    if ($(lastSelected).attr("src") == $(el).find("img").attr("src") && $(lastSelected).hasClass("visible")) {
        score = 0 + 2;
        alert("Congradulation! You scored!!" + " " + score + " Points");
    }

    lastSelected = $(el).find("img");
    clearAll();

}


function click() {

    var boxes = $(".row img").size();
    $(".row div").click(function () {
        moves++;
        $(".totalmoves").html(moves);
        $(".cover").css({
            "z-index": "9999"
        });
        $(this).children("img").animate({
            "opacity": "1"
        }, function () {
            num++;
            var id1 = $("img.selected").attr("src");
            var id2 = $(this).attr("src");
            $(this).addClass("selected");

            if (num == 2) {
                num = 0;
                if (id1 == id2) {
                    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
                    score = score + 2;
                    alert("Congradulation! You scored!!" + " " + score + " Points");
                    boxes = boxes - 2;
                    if (boxes == 0) {
                        alert("Game Over Your Total Score is :" + score + " Points");
                    }

                    $(".yourscore").html(score);
                } else {
                    speed = 100;
                    $(".selected").animate({
                        "opacity": "0"
                    }, 400, function () {
                        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
                        if (score > 1) {
                            score = score - 0.5;
                            $(".yourscore").html(score);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                speed = 100;
            }

            $(this).animate({
                "padding": "0.1"
            }, speed, function () {
                $(".cover").css({
                    "z-index": "-9999"
                });
            });
        });

    });


};

// add Random Images
function addImg() {

    var images = ["http://courses.oreillyschool.com/jquery/QuizzesAndProjects/images/cheese.gif", "http://courses.oreillyschool.com/jquery/QuizzesAndProjects/images/eggs.gif", "http://courses.oreillyschool.com/jquery/QuizzesAndProjects/images/kitchen_blender.gif", "http://courses.oreillyschool.com/jquery/QuizzesAndProjects/images/tea.gif", "http://courses.oreillyschool.com/jquery/QuizzesAndProjects/images/kitchen_collander.gif", "http://courses.oreillyschool.com/jquery/QuizzesAndProjects/images/kitchen_teapot.gif"];

    var imagesused = [];
    $('.container div:not(.row)').each(function () {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
        $(this).append('<img src="' + images[rand] + '"/>');
        if (imagesused.indexOf(images[rand]) != -1) images.splice(rand, 1);
        else imagesused.push(images[rand]);
        console.log(images);

    });
}
// Clear the images Button
var clearAll = function () {
    $(':button').click(function () {
        score = 0;
        $(".yourscore").html(score);
        moves = 0;
        $(".totalmoves").html(moves);
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        $(".row img").animate({
            "opacity": "0"
        }, function () {
            $(".row img").remove();
            addImg();

        });




    });

};
```

html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>jQuery: Manipulating and Traversing Elements Project</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
div.container, div.row, form {
  clear: both;
}
div.row > div {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 170px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px grey;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
div.row > div > img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  bottom: 30px;
}
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.done {
  visibility: visible;
}

.cover{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:-9999;  
}

.row img{
  opacity:0;
}

.scoreboard{
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 31px 5px 10px;
  border-radius:5px;
}
.scoreboard span{

}

form{
  float:left;
}

.playagain{
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
}
</style>  
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
          <script src="game.js"> </script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <form>
            <input type="button" value="Play again">
          </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```